# Connect Azure SQL database with on prem Tableau server

Tags: azure-sql-database, firewall, tableau-desktop, database-connectivity

I need to connect an on premises Tableau report server, whose port 433 is open, with Azure SQL server with port 1433 open.

Direct connectivity from on-prem Tableau desktop app with Azure SQL server is not possible due to difference in the ports.

How can this be achieved? Connectivity to Azure sql database from on prem Tableau desktop app to create reports.

Comment: Q: What do you mean "Direct connectivity from on-prem Tableau desktop app with Azure SQL server is not possible due to difference in the ports"?  Can't the Tableau report server simply communicate with MSSQL on port 1433? Then your desktop app communicates with Tableau.

Comment: You just need to open the firewall ports between the Azure Cloud desktop and your on-prem network , any network expert can do this in the firewall settings

Comment: Opening further firewall ports is not allowed due to security restrictions, so need to make this work via workaround or something using existing configuration

Comment: Can't the Tableau report server simply communicate with MSSQL on port 1433? @FoggyDay - Can you please share further details or any example here.

Comment: your server is in aws?